# Is there a way to set up structured streaming with pyspark from Kafka to Cassandra

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing some script for analytics in Pyspark. And I can not set up streaming to Cassandra from Kafka. When it's one data it is ok, but when is streaming it wont work.

I'm reading about some way with `foreachBatch`, but I'm new in Pyspark, and I can't successfully write down that, because documentation for that is lame.

Can someone help me about `foreachBatch` in my script.

I'm providing datas from Kafka topic to Cassandra.

```
import os, json, time
from pyspark.sql import  functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def parse_value(value):
    value_object = json.loads(value)
    return [value_object["topicData"]["serialNumber"]+":"+str(value_object["msg"]["params"]["device_id"])+":"+str(value_object["msg"]["timestamp"]),
    value_object["msg"]["params"]["service_name"],
    str(value_object["msg"]["timestamp"]),
    value_object["msg"]["params"]["property_value"]]



parse_value_udf = F.udf(lambda x: parse_value(x), types.ArrayType(types.StringType()))

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "topicsForEvents123") \
  .load() \
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")


df = df.withColumn('_id', parse_value_udf(df.value)[0]).withColumn('property_name', parse_value_udf(df.value)[1]).withColumn('time', parse_value_udf(df.value)[2]).withColumn('value', parse_value_udf(df.value)[3])

df = df.select('_id','property_name','time','value')
query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .option("property_change","strat_history_keyspace_cassandra_raw1")\
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I just want someone to show me example of `foreachBatch` in Pyspark on this script, if it is ok to try. Because I can't understand documentation and how to put this, with my piece of code.

DOCUMENTATION SAYS:

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    # Transform and write batchDF
    pass

streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

And I can't understand how to send `df` and `epoch_id`. Where to find `id`, and which exactly `df` to send function as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`foreachBatch` is an output sink that let you process each streaming micro-batch as a non-streaming dataframe.

If you want to try a minimal working example you can just print the dataframe to the console:

```py
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    df.show()

df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

There is nothing else to do.

Spark reads from the input stream (Kafka) continuously and send each micro-batch to the function you defined (`foreach_batch_function`) automatically.
The function will receive the dataframe and the batch id. You don't have to call the function manually.
At this point you can treat the dataframe as a batch dataframe and perform all the transformations and actions you want.

If you want to output the micro-batch dataframe to Cassandra you need to edit the `foreach_batch_function` function like

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    df.write \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .mode('append') \
        .options(table="TABLE_NAME", keyspace="KEYSPACE_NAME") \
        .save()
```

Comment: Thanks @vinsce.  Your solution was precisely what I was looking for.  Cheers!